# mongoDB : How to get most recent fields of an embedded document(non-array)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Maybe I'm going against the grain here, but I've structured data where the a message thread
lives inside a document and all the messages lives inside an embedded document.(not subdocument array)

I would like to be able to sort and limit the embedded document by the timestamp.

For example the second document is rather large so I'd like to only retrieve the last 10 messages(or w/e)
between Bob and myself.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("2bjbkjb4234j134124"), 
    "messages" : {
        "56a7b13f24236dea1247cdc7" : {
            "authorName" : "Nick", 
            "timestamp" : 1.453699391078E12, 
            "message" : "Hello"
        },
        ... 5 more messages
    }

},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("3e11kjb4234j134172"), 
    "messages" : {
        "5727b13f24236dea1247ced8" : {
            "authorName" : "Bob", 
            "timestamp" : 1.2353453455078E12, 
            "message" : "Sup!"
        },
        ... 50,000 messages
    }

}
```

Question:

Is there a way to do the equivalent of sort,limit and return but on an embedded document(like the messages above)?

Comment: Not with the design above, unless you restructure the schema so that you can embed the subdocuments in an array rather than in a hash key, your best bet would be MapReduce.

Comment: Really appreciate the quick response. It will be sad to drop hash keys :(  I imagined they would be more speedy for realtime updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should be using arrays here, as using named object keys is really 
counterintuitive to how a database basically works.

Aside from the basic querying problems, such as maybe looking for all content by author "Bob" in a collection ( which is simple with arrays ), you have similar "brute force" matching problems in looking for the "last 10". Not to mention, as a "non-array" it becomes really subjective what the "last ten" actually is.

Even taking the example that supposing these "keys" are actually the same generated values of MongoDB `ObjectID` values ( therefore being monotonic and always increasing in value ), working out the sort order of these requires brute force JavaScript processing with no assistance from collection indexes or natural array index positions:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var messages = this.messages;
        var newMessages = Object.keys(this.messages).sort().slice(-10).map(
            function(id) {
                return messages[id];
            }
        );

        emit(this._id,{ "messages": newMessages });
    },
    function() {},   // not really reducing anything here
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Or simillar juggling by the "timestamp" values ( which does not look like a timestamp ), but the basic premise here is turning something that is **not** an array into an array, in order to sort the results and limit those you want to return.

Basically **Ugly!**, and really bad design. Also just using mapReduce for the sake of that it is the only method ( via JavaScript processing ) of altering the structure of the document returned. The logic may as well be performed in the client, with the only advantage of stripping unwanted content before sending over the network connection.

The idea that using arrays imposes some overhead on "updating" content is fairly "bunk" as well. MongoDB has supported matched position updating since inception, and structuring correctly as well as usage is fairly straightforward:

```js
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("2bjbkjb4234j134124"), 
    "messages" : [
        {
            "_id": "56a7b13f24236dea1247cdc7",
            "authorName" : "Nick", 
            "timestamp" : 1.453699391078E12, 
            "message" : "Hello"
        },
        // etc
    ]
}
```

So if you wanted to match and update a specific array entry ( assuming unqiue everywhere, but just a matter of tuning to "per-document" if needed ) just applies the identifier in the query portion and the positional `$` operator in the "update" portion of the statement:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "messages._id": "56a7b13f24236dea1247cdc7" },
    { "$set": {
        "messages.$.message": "something new",
        "messages.$.timestamp": aNewValue
    }}
)
```

Adding items to arrays using `$push` also has the advantage of all "newest" entries are added to the end of the array by default. So unless you change this ( and don't modify and thus want latest timestamp ) then all you need do is `$slice` the "already an array", without further juggling:

```js
db.collection.find(
    {},
    { "messages": { "$slice": -10 } }
)
```

If you really wanted a modified field such as "timestamp" to affect the ordering, then you could simply store that way usign the `$sort` modifier to `$push`. This can even apply to modified array elements by simple application of Bulk Operations:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

// Update the matched element
bulk.find({ 
    "_id": ObjectId("2bjbkjb4234j134124"),
    "messages._id": "56a7b13f24236dea1247cdc7"
}).updateOne({
    "$set": {
        "messages.$.message": "something new",
        "messages.$.timestamp": aNewValue
    }
});

// Sort the array on timestamp
bulk.find({ 
    "_id": ObjectId("2bjbkjb4234j134124"),
    "messages._id": "56a7b13f24236dea1247cdc7"
}).updateOne({
    "$push": { "messages": { "$each": [], "$sort": { "timestamp": 1 } } }
})

// Send and receive from server
bulk.execute();
```

Which while this is effectively two update statements ( since you cannot modify the same document path with two operator statements in a single update operation ), it does still work out as a single request and response to the server, and is therefore pretty efficient.

And of course if you did not want to store the order permanantly, then arrays can at least be manipulated in the aggregation framework, in a manner that will usually be more efficient than processing via JavaScript of mapReduce:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": ObjectId("2bjbkjb4234j134124") },
    { "$unwind": "$messages" },
    { "$sort": { "messages.timestamp": -1 } },    // in reverse order with $limit
    { "$limit": 10 },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "messages": { "$push": "$messages" }
    }}
])
```

Or even super fancy over multiple documents with new MongoDB 3.2 operators:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$messages" },
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "messages.timestamp": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "messages": { "$push": "$messages" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "messages": { "$slice": [ "$messages", -10 ] }
    }}
])
```

But the most performant consideration in all cases is that the data should:

1. Be an "array" and not nested under named keys of an object
2. Ideally be stored in the order of the most common use case for access on reading.

The final thing to really look at here is that if you "really" intend to store 50,000 messages in an array or even a single document ( because no-one ever exaggerates wildly when asking questions on StackOverflow ) then these would always be better off existing in their own collection, where even if the BSON document limit were not exceeded ( the most likely event would be it was exceeded ), the performance considerations would indeed be terrible.

Considering usage patterns of the data should be the prime objective here. So just because you "can" store referenced documents within another, unless you have a use case where "all of them" ( definately never 50,000 ) are needed in one request, then you should not be doing so.

Comment: wow, I'm going to have to study this post to understand all the points you made, but I can tell that great insight were poured here. I will follow up soon on how it turned out! Meanwhile I hope this post gets the up votes it deserves because it should be visible.

Comment: Thanks again @BlakesSeven this post had me go back and rethink everything about my structure!